# Writing the modulus below the equivalence symbol -- unable to get this to work

Tags: math-mode

New to LaTex, have a good reference but this isn't in it.

Instead of writing `x \equiv 3 mod n`, I would like the `3` to appear under the `\equiv` symbol.  Neither `\underset` nor `\overset` do what I require, because the `\equiv` symbol should be on the same level as `x` and `n`.  Any ideas why the following isn't working?

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mymod}{\equiv}
$x \mymod_3 n$
```

When I typeset this, 3 still appears below and to the right, as a conventional subscript, and not directly under it like I want.  Any ideas?  Thanks.,

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: You shouldn't use `\DeclareMathOperator`, but `\underset{3}{\equiv}`

Comment: Mathematically, I would rather write *n* under the congruience symbol…

Answer (score 7):

`\DeclareMathOperator` is the wrong tool, because it's, well, for operators, not for relation symbols.

You just need `\underset{3}{\equiv}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$x \equiv 3\pmod{n}$

$x \equiv_{n} 3$

$x \underset{n}{\equiv} 3$

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid the third method, though, because it creates too deep a symbol, making for uneven lines when used in line.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you also add `$x \overset{n}{\equiv} 3$`.